# Convert SQL retrieve result into a string in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a retrieve statement that goes like this

```
$arrayAID = request('agentID');
    $sizeAID = count($arrayAID);
    $aidList = "null";
    for($a = 0; $a < $sizeAID; $a++){
        $email = DB::table('insuranceAgents')
                 ->select('email')
                 ->where('agentID', '=', $arrayAID[$a])
                 ->get();
        dd($email);
    }
```

which returns the result

[image]

What can I do to modify this $email to only get "simcatcat@gmail.com" as my result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`value()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#retrieving-results) method:

```
DB::table('insuranceAgents')->where('agentID', $arrayAID[$a])->value('email');
```

`value('email')` is a shortcut for `->first()->email`

> You may extract a single value from a record using the `value` method. This method will return the value of the column directly

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#retrieving-results

Answer (score 1):

You can use `->first()` . In your case,

```
$arrayAID = request('agentID');
$sizeAID = count($arrayAID);
$aidList = "null";
for($a = 0; $a < $sizeAID; $a++){
    $email = DB::table('insuranceAgents')
             ->select('email')
             ->where('agentID', '=', $arrayAID[$a])
             ->get()->first();
    dd($email);
}
```